# Reverse transform by rearrainging terms

Tags: linear-transformations

I have a simple affine transform equation:
$$ x' = a + bx + cy \\ y' = d + ex + fy $$

I found some code that states that through a rearrangement of terms you can find the following reversed transformation:
$$ x = (f(x' - a) - cy' + dc) / (bf - ce) \\ y = (e(x' - a) - by' + db) / (ce - bf) $$

I have tested it and seen that it works, but how was it derived?

Answer (score 2):

The transform is $$\begin{bmatrix}
b & c \\
e & f \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
d \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
b &c \\
e &f \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
x'-a \\
y'-d \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $$\begin{bmatrix}
b &c \\
e &f \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}={1\over bf-ce}\begin{bmatrix}
f &-c \\
-e &b \\
\end{bmatrix}$$